# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi randomly disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I have a network issue on Ubuntu 20.04. Wifi randomly disconnects about every 30-45 minutes or whenever I am having a zoom call or I am watching videos in streaming. I tried to fix this by disabling the power management on the wifi card, but it didn't solve my problem. Any idea? My kernel version is 5.4.0-51-generic. Please help me, this is very annoying.

Comment: We don't know what is your "wifi card".

Comment: There have been some issues with the -51 kernel. Run `Software Updater` and get the newer -52 kernel and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Ok, now I have the -52 version. I'll use it for a while and I'll make you know if I have still issues

Comment: I have also issues with the intel audio card, randomly booting recognizing only the mic (when I reboot after this issue it often works), but this seems not fixed in the -52 version

Comment: @heynnema I have still troubles, even after having upgraded  the kernel to -52 I still managed to trigger the bug

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `iwlist scan` and `iwlist freq` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Do you have QoS enabled in your router? Are you running with a VPN?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this similar problem on Ubuntu 20.10, Gnome 3.38.1, by going to Settings > Power > Power Saving > Automatic Suspend > Off.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone has any news on this issues, I tried those solutions as well but it's still coming up.

I run `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and it shows `A10`.

Then `sudo lshw -C network` shows :

```
  `*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 73
   serial: f8:16:54:55:e2:f9
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet 
   physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-50- 
   generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode ip=192.168.0.56 
   latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:49 memory:e3500000-e3501fff`
```