# 20.04 WIFI keeps hard blocking randomly

Tags: 20.04, realtek-wireless, ralink, wifi-hardware-switch

as the title suggests, by WIFI keeps getting hard blocked randomly.
This happens in middle of some video stream or even if it is idle.

I have tried disabling automatic suspend in Settings > Power as suggested in [Ubuntu 20.04 wifi randomly disconnecting](https://askubuntu.com/q/1285997/855094) but to no help.

I have a RaLink RT3090 1T/1R internal WIFI adapter and a RealTek RTL8188EUS USB adapter. Both are disabled when this happens.

Below are the list of commands which @heynnema suggested in one of the comments.

I am happy to provide any other outputs as needed, please help me solve this issue.

Except for `rfkill list all` all other commands were executed when WIFI was not hard blocked.

**rfkill list all**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 1c:4b:d6:64:07:62
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.4.0-65-generic firmware=0.40 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:f0500000-f050ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: c0
       serial: 70:71:bc:4f:d6:e7
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:31 memory:f0400000-f043ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1.2
       logical name: wlxd03745258658
       serial: d0:37:45:25:86:58
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.0.118 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

**iwlist scan**

```
enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0    No scan results

wlxd03745258658  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 8C:53:C3:5C:38:DF
                    ESSID:"Varun"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie=dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f202
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30180100000fac020200000fac02000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD7E0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700102880288028801880A8808C53C35C38DF102100067869616F6D69102300045234434D10240004303030321042000831323334353637381054000800060050F20400011011000C5869616F4D69526F7574657210080002210C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=23/100  
          Cell 02 - Address: 3C:84:6A:D5:94:4C
                    ESSID:"Hansy"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30180100000fac020200000fac02000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD7F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001038833092309218839C773C846AD594C41021000754502D4C696E6B10230009544C2D57523835304E10240003332E3010420003312E301054000800060050F20400011011000D544C2D57523835304E20332E3010080002210C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=47/100  
          Cell 03 - Address: 50:D4:F7:30:6A:56
                    ESSID:"Optimus2"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie=dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2020050f20401000050f202
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30180100000fac020200000fac02000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=100/100  Signal level=93/100  
          Cell 04 - Address: 1C:7E:E5:53:F2:99
                    ESSID:"Optimus1"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:108 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30180100000fac020200000fac04000fac020100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=39/100  
          Cell 05 - Address: 70:3A:CB:CA:15:8B
                    ESSID:"sagar"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=23/100  
          Cell 06 - Address: A0:04:60:10:93:F5
                    ESSID:"sagar_EXT"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD8D0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700102880288028801880A880A004601093F5102100044E54475210230008574E3330303052501024000256331042000C6130303436303130393366351054000800060050F204000110110017574E333030305250763328576972656C6573732041502910080002210C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=23/100
```

**iwlist freq**

```
enp3s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp2s0    14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
wlxd03745258658  11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

**free -h**

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          1.8Gi       913Mi       145Mi       470Mi       790Mi       304Mi
Swap:         1.9Gi       235Mi       1.6Gi
```

**sysctl vm.swappiness**
`vm.swappiness = 60`

**sudo dmidecode -s bios-version**
`204.T01`

**UPDATE**

`sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` output: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5T4FHHrc)

Comment: Both WiFi adapters are on and you are trying to use both at once?

Comment: Yes, both are on at once, but the problem persists even after I remove my USB adapter.

Comment: switch one you remove and reboot after each removal

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Otherwise there could be combination of control plus a function key to unblock your adapter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately this does not help. I have a combination of keys to unblock, but it keep on disconnecting very frequently and have to do it regularly.